How to set the foldlevel differently for function and class when loading a Python file?
To have an overview of a Python script I like to have:

The global functions folded (foldlevel 0)
The classes unfolded and all their methods folded (foldlevel 1)

def foo():
    print("foo")

class Bar:
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = "bar"

    def bar(self):
        print("bar")

Appearing has:
def foo():                                 +++
class Bar:
    def __init__(self):                    +++
    def bar(self):                         +++

I can achieve that with:
setlocal foldlevel=0
g/^class\s\+/norm zo

I would like that statement being executed when I read the python file.
I have tried to put ~/.vim/after/ftplugin/python.vim:
g/^class\s\+/norm zo

But it seems that the two events are triggered too early. The fold are probably not set yet and the call that unfold the class is doing nothing.
Is there an event that I can use?
Is there another way to achieve the same?

Gives me E490 No fold found. I'm assuming you're using foldmethod=syntax. Where do you specify your settings? Autocommands trigger in the order they were defined so maybe a little reordering can solve this.

Thanks @Friedrich, I'll investigate more I put the autocmd in ~/.vim/after/ftplugin/python.vim thinking it should be quite late but I'll analyze more.

Once you’re in (after/)ftplugin, you are already working with a buffer. Try doing the global command on its own from such a file

@D.BenKnoble when I run the command on the buffer it does what I expect. But when it is triggered by the autocommand it does nothing, most probably because the folds are not created yet.

Sorry: I mean don’t put the :global in an autocommand in an ftplugin, just out the global command in the ftplugin.

Thanks to @Friedrich and @D.BenKnoble the solution was to put the following autocmd:
autocmd FileType python g/^class\s\+/norm zo

Right after the command that set the fold (I'm using vim-anyfold):
autocmd Filetype python AnyFoldActivate

If put after the code that triggers the creation of the fold it triggers the code that open the folds when the fold are created.
